# Inno Setup: Deleting folders after restart during uninstallation

Tags: windows, inno-setup, uninstallation

I have a question about deleting folders during uninstallation using Inno Setup.

In my script, I use the `uninsrestartdelete` flag on some files and call `DelTree` on the `{app}` folder on the last step of uninstallation. Sometimes, I can't delete all files until system restart (those are code injection DLLs). In this situation, I can't delete the `{app}` folder successfully. What's the correct way to delete the `{app}` folder on system restart as well? I can make sure there is no file left in the folder When I try to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To schedule file or directory deletion on restart, call [`RestartReplace` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_restartreplace) with `DestFile` (second) argument set to an empty string (`''`).

```pascal
RestartReplace(FileToDelete, '');
```

For directories, this works, only if they are empty. So you will have to first call `RestartReplace` for all files inside the directory, which cannot be deleted.

For details, refer to [WinAPI function `MoveFileEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefileexw) and its `MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT` flag, which is behind the Inno Setup `RestartReplace` function.